# Entity Framework - updating record

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I know it has been asked before, but I am still unable to fix the following error, when updating or deleting record with entity framework:

[image]

I am trying to update a row with the following code, where user variable is parameter, passed into the method:

```
savedUser = context.Users.Attach(user);
context.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
context.SaveChanges();
```

I am also using same code to update 2 other entities and there it works. 
Also, here is my DataContext class:

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    private static DataContext instance = new DataContext();
    public static DataContext Instance
    {
        get { return DataContext.instance; }
    }

    public DataContext() : base("DataContext")
    {
    }
}
```

Any tips?

Comment: It seems that you're trying to update the record, not deleting it. If you want to delete it, set the state to `EntityState.Deleted`.

Comment: Yes, made a mistake there. I am trying to update it, but I am getting same error, when deleting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the entity is already attached, and you don't need to attach it again. So the attach needs to be called only if the entity is not already attached like this:

```
bool isAttached = context.Users.Local.Any(x => x == user);
if(!isAttached)
    contect.Users.Attach(user);

context.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
context.SaveChanges();
```

**UPDATE**

When using an existing context, which was used previously for load operations (connected mode), try this:

```
context.Users.AddOrUpdate(user);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Or, try creating a brand new context for each major operation (aka disconnected mode):

```
using(var newContext = new DataContext())
{
    var attachedUser = newContext.Users.Attach(user);
    newContext.Entry(attachedUser).State = EntityState.Modified;
    newContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

From my past experience with EF, I recommend using disconnected mode (i.e., creating a new DbContext for each major operation). One main reason is DbContext does not recover properly from errors and exceptions, and you may need to manage its life-time manually. While in disconnected mode, you'll be confident that you'll be using a fresh and clean DbContext without worrying about its state.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but this still gives me the same error.

Comment: @Orochi I imagine your entities have Id. Can you change the first line to the following and see if it works: `bool isAttached = context.Users.Local.Any(x => x.Id == user.Id);`

Comment: Well, still the same. Anyway, I just checked something and exception is actually thrown at this line:
`context.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;`

Comment: @Orochi I added an update. Could you try that one too?

Comment: Well, that doesn't work either. No exception is trown but record is also not updated. I don't understand, why my code for updating works on other entities, but does not work on User entity.

Comment: @Orochi which one did you try? Did you try the disconnected mode?

Comment: I just fixed my problem. What I did is read the entity from database again and then asign every property of my changed entity to that entity and saved it. Then I tried your "connected mode" and it also worked. I have been using "disconnected mode" before, but I ran at some problem, don't remember exactly, but it was like "different datacontexts accessing same entity". That's why I changed it to singleton. Is that a bad practice? Anyway, thainks for help, means alot to me!

Comment: @Orochi No problems. Yes you cannot attach a single entity to multiple contexts. But if you kill a context before you instantiate the next one (e.g., like subsequent using blocks, not nested), then you can make sure you don't have more than 1 context alive at the same time. I'm not generally that experienced in EF to say what you're doing is good or bad practise. But I had lots of problems with the connected mode, especially with error handling.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are trying to add a record that already exists, but you said that you were trying to delete the record.  Either way, [this](http://pragmaticcoding.com/index.php/entity-framework-insert-update-delete-records/) link may be of good use to you.