# Entity Framework update database records

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I did search for similar scenarios but not sure which approach I should take.

So my case is like I have a list of records from the view need to insert/update from a database table, the table is like PrimaryID, PersonID1, PersonID2 and RelationshipID.

When I retrieve the data from the view, which I will be getting PersonID1, PersonID2 and RelationshipID(no PrimaryID), do I need to do a search first from the table to check whether there is any existing records from the list, if yes then do nothing, else insert or remove existing records which is in database but not in the list of records I get from the view. Or there is a more simple way to achieve this?

I have seen scenarios like: [Entity Framework - updating record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27262506/entity-framework-updating-record)
But not sure if my case would be similar.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not sure but I think you are looking for this
`var checkPersonID1 = _EntityObj.tbl_name.Where(a => a.PersonID1.Equals(PersonID1)).FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: @DipSurani, thanks. So you are suggesting I should do a lookup on each record in the list to the database first, if it is not then, insert. And if the database table has records not in the list, it should be removed?

Comment: You can check var is empty or not than you can perform your action `var checkPersonID1 = _EntityObj.tbl_name.Where(a => a.PersonID1.Equals(PersonID1)).FirstOrDefault();` `if(checkPersonID1 ==null) { // add recod} else{ // remove or updated record }`

Comment: @DipSurani Thanks. This is what I thought initially. Not sure if there is any built-in feature in entity framework which can handle this kind of bulk update/insert/delete option, so I thought I'd better ask here.

Comment: Enjoy !! Happy coding